# Unable to find explicit activity class Android

Tags: java, android

Ugh, so many posts on StackOverflow similar to my problem but none fix it :/

I am currently learning android development. In my main activity I do:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     switch(item.getItemId()){
         case R.id.changeName:
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreferenceActivity.class);
             startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
             return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Preference.java is a freshly created activity with nothing in it except the automatically created onCreate method. The error is:

```
  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.package.chat.oneway.client/android.preference.PreferenceActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

My android manifest has:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".ChatClient"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name=".Parent">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PreferenceActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

As you can see, .PreferenceActivity is in the manifest. The packages for the ChatClient and PreferenceActivity activities are the same com.package.chat.oneway.client package.It's been driving me nuts for the past 4 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see, .PreferenceActivity is in the manifest.

Yes, it is. However, that is not what your `Intent` is using. If you look more closely at the error message, you will see that your `Intent` is using `android.preference.PreferenceActivity`.

This comes when you reuse existing class names. There are countless possible class names. Rename yours to something else, and you can avoid this sort of problem in the future.

Or, if you are completely set on having your class named `PreferenceActivity`, then remove the `import android.preference.PreferenceActivity` statement from the class where you are creating your `Intent`. Or, change your `Intent` to:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.package.chat.oneway.client.PreferenceActivity.class);
```

Comment: That worked! I removed the import statement for right now. I didnt realize it was conflicting with the name. Many thanks